# Condense pivot cell selects

Tags: excel, vba

I was just wondering if there is a way to condense this down to minimal code?
I am using lastrow for my end worksheet (the sheet my code generates after all is said and done with the pivot table), and lastrow2 is assisting in grabbing the range for the pivot table source data. I am not sure if lastrow2 is even required though?

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("1:1").Delete 'Report title
    'Adding pivot table
        Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Pivot"
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase,     SourceData:= _
            "FNDWRR!A1:M" & lastrow2,     Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
            TableDestination:="Pivot!R3C1", TableName:="StatPivot"
```

Comment: I would personally just use `Range("A1").Currentregion` to get the right range for the pivot.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? It won't take `SourceData:= Range("A1").Currentregion` because it says it needs more than one cell. Not sure how it's only pulling one cell though.